# Coordinates and stationary point.

Tags: derivatives

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{lnx}$ for $x>1$

a) Derive expressions for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$, simplifying the answer.

b) Obtain the coordinates and nature of the stationary point of the y=f(x).

c) Obtain the coordinates of the point of inflection.

Comment: Part a) would be: $f'(x)=\frac{lnx-1}{ln^2x}$ and $f''(x)=\frac{2-lnx}{xln^3x}$

Comment: However what will be required for part b) and c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln x}\;,$$ Now $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x}{\ln x}\right] = \frac{\ln x\cdot (x)'-x\cdot (\ln x)'}{(\ln x)^2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{\ln x-1}{(\ln x)^2}$$

Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(f'(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\ln x-1}{(\ln x)^2}\right] = \frac{(\ln x)^2\cdot (\ln x-1)'-(\ln x-1)\cdot ((\ln x)^2)'}{(\ln x)^4}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle f''(x) = \frac{(\ln x)^2\cdot x^{-1}-(\ln x-1)\cdot 2\ln x\cdot x^{-1}}{(\ln x)^4} = \frac{2-\ln x}{x\cdot (\ln x)^3}$$

$(b)$ For Stationary point, Put $f'(x)=0,$ So we get $$\ln x-1=0\Rightarrow \ln x= 1\Rightarrow x=e$$

If $f'(x)>0\;,$ Means for $x>e,$ Function $f(x)$ is strictly Increasing function.

and for $f'(x)<0,$ Means for $x<e,$ Function $f(x)$ is strictly Decreasing function.

Now For Concavity of function, We will use $\bf{Sign}$ of $f''(x)$ at $x=e$

Here  $f''(e)>0,$ So function $f(x)$ is Concave Upward.

$(c)$ For Point of Inflection, $f''(x)=0$ and $f'''(x)\neq 0$

So $\displaystyle f''(x)=0\Rightarrow 2-\ln x=0\Rightarrow x=e^2$

Comment: Thanks juantheron, but how would you find the coordinates and nature of the stationary point of the y=f(x)  -  for part b)

Comment: How would you describe the nature

Comment: What would be the y coordinate. would you just sub in the value of x to find it.

Comment: Why is the numerator looked upon to find the value of x.

Comment: bcz denominator is positive for  $x>1$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{x}{lnx}$ for $x>1$ $f'(x)=\frac{1\ln x-\frac{1}{x}x}{ln^2 x}=\frac{\ln x-1}{ln^2 x}$

and $f''(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{x}ln^2 x-2\frac{1}{x}\ln x(lnx -1)}{ln^4 x}$

$f'(x)=0$ then $\ln x-1 =0$ so $\ln x=1 $  that gives $x=e$

$f''(x)=0=\frac{1}{x}ln^2 x-2\frac{1}{x}\ln x(lnx -1)=\frac{1}{x} ln x(ln x-2(lnx-1))$ thus $x=1$ or $ln x-2(lnx-1))=0$ that gives $-lnx=1$ hence $x= e^{-1}$
 also for $ln^ 4 x=0 $, $f''(x)$ doesnot exist. where happenes in $x=1$

Comment: Thanks guys but how would you do part b) and c)

Comment: How would you describe the nature of the stationary point

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives are found by others who responded, coincides with my quotient rule shortcut also.

By nature of stationary point, you are asked whether it is a maximum or minimum, that is all.

Minimum at $x=e , $ as derivative vanishes and second derivative >0.

When second derivative is zero, point of inflection at $ x=e^2 $.

Comment: Why is the numerator looked at from $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ to find the value of x.

Comment: If $x/y =0, x =0 $ To find minimum, first derivative should vanish . So dont look at denominator, Similarly  for inflection second  derivative should vanish . Likewise dont look at denominator,